# Azure Mobile App and AngularJS responsive in same host space

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to get ride of "This mobile app is up and running" page and when user enters the sitename redirect/route him to sitename/app folder where I can pretty much create a AngularJS website in my project folder. FYI - I'm a Dev beginner

using Custom site URL in Azure: I tried this and working pretty like,

- when I open the site (www.testsite.com) it's taking me to blue screen
- when I go to (www.testsite.com/app) it displays my AngularJS app that I am trying deploy along with and in same mobile app serivce
- REST API services and details under www.testsite.com/swagger

why I am trying this ?
On a typical note I want my app to serve all devices, web, mobile, tablet and I feel that mobile app solution is the only lean solution to do rapid application development but wondering how to reach web users without creating an other Web App services in Azure only for Views or web client which comes with cost. let us say if mobile service is just a backend stack and it doesn't allow it... I wonder why not ? by doing it, developers don't need to create 2 services in azure (1. mobile app, 2. web app)

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

found work around by adding MVC Razor Home controller and view for home landing page. more information in this link. this may be a temp solution to get ride of Blue screen and I am going to explore more in include AngularJS site and routing from angular too.

Since this solution works with only MVC style routing there will be a conflict between routing mechanics. will update as soon as I get something.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f23175db-2a83-489f-ac0c-f2abe9e48a76/default-document-for-the-mobile-app?forum=azuremobile

If Home view not showing up refer this link.

[The view 'Index' or its master was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209990/the-view-index-or-its-master-was-not-found)