# ASP.net MVC Razor view on Mono Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I created an ASP.net MVC application using Visual Studio Community Edition for Mac. When I ran the default HomeController and Index view work fine. Then I made a BookController and inside views added a folder Book and Index.cshtml file. However I keep getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException The view found at
>   '~/Views/book/Index.cshtml' was not created.

Description:

> HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details:

> Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object):
>   System.Web.Mvc. Exception stack trace:   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer)
>   [0x00061] in :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00080] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext,
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32
>   filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext,
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0000b] in
>   <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32
>   filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext,
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0009b] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters,
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0000a] in
>   <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21+<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c
>   () [0x0008a] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00041] in
>   <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[TResult].CallEndDelegate
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End
>   () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult]
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in
>   <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in
>   <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState innerState)
>   [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at (wrapper
>   delegate-invoke)
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState]:invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState
>   (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.Controller/ExecuteCoreState)   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in
>   <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End
>   () [0x00029] in :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult]
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15 (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in
>   <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End
>   () [0x00029] in :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult]
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState innerState) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at (wrapper delegate-invoke)
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState]:invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState
>   (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler/ProcessRequestState)
>
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End
>   () [0x00029] in :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult]
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest
>   (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.async_handler_complete_cb
>   (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x00015] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class

I Googled around and people said I have to make sure the web.config inside views folder is as follows:

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

That is it matches the version of system.web.mvc and looking inside system.web.mvc the version is:

**5.2.3**

And the default view in HomeController works. I am trying out ASP.net MVC on Mac first time and never had this type of problem on Windows.

Any help is welcome.

Update Controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestMvcFromMac.Models;

namespace TestMvcFromMac.Controllers
{
 public class BookController : Controller
 {

    //Category category = new Category();


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View ();
    }


 }
}
```

Comment: can you show controller code here please!

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj yup controller code please. we cant just answer without debugging your code.

Comment: I have added the controller code, Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: What is the content of the Index.cshtml?

Answer (score 2):

medium 
Visual Studio for Mac 2017 
MVC version 5.3.2

I had the exact same problem. My Index views was working and  other actions was not,  giving the same error.  I don't know why but when I add a route attribute manually in the beginning of the action in the controller, it was the solutions for my case

steps 
1) add following line to the routeconfig.cs file

```
 routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

2) add route attribute to the action manually 
like

```
  [Route("ViewName/ActionName/")]
    public ActionResult ActionName()
    {....
  return View(the_model);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just run into the same problem when opening up a previously-developed MVC 5 application on VS for Mac. I know there was nothing wrong with it before - it was originally put together using VS 2015 on Windows and subsequently moved to 2017 and regularly updated over the months/years. However upon opening and running on the Mac, this same issue arose.

After much head-banging, I've discovered that the problem only occurs when accessing the URL using lower-case. In my case at least, that is expected because the `RouteConfig` class has `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` within. Accessing a failing page by explicitly capitalising the characters or after commenting out that line makes it work as expected.

I'm assuming it's a case of Unix-style case-sensitivity somewhere under the covers.

I haven't yet found a solution (changing the casing of the URLs isn't an acceptable workaround for me) but if it is in your case then it may solve the problem. If I do find a more appropriate solution, I will update this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the problem might happen because you are creating all the stuff manually and not letting template engine generate something for you like in visual studio in windows *(Personally did not try Mac version so I dont know exactly how it looks like)*. Anyway lets suppose you have created your controller and then Book folder. But there is something to configure manually as well if its not configured, and that is routing for current controller.

You have to set routing logic in `RouteConfig` file class, so you would have something like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Book" , action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Refere to this question for more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209990/the-view-index-or-its-master-was-not-found).

Another version I guess is setting the view name inside return statement itself like this:

```
return View("Index")
```

If this is not the case please let me know so I can see any other alternative for this problem...

Comment: See it did create the route config, And ASP.net matches the action name to find a view. If you see it does say the View was found but was not created.

Comment: using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace TestMvcFromMac
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

Comment: Also for the proof of concept if its a routing problem which i was knowing it is not, still I returned "Hello World" string and it did router properly no erros just return View wont work

Answer (score 0):

Arrived at a simple solution that worked for me. Inherit from a base controller or add these methods to your existing base controller.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected ViewResult View(object models, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
    {
        return base.View(callerName, models);
    }

    protected new ViewResult View([CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
    {
        return base.View(callerName);
    }
}
```